# Have neovim load a file from file explorer

Tags: bash, .desktop, vim, terminator, neovim

I would like to have neovim as a default text editor also when accessed from file explorer.

When I choose it from the "open with" dialogue or when it is the default for some file extension I'm clicking, it opens the file in neovim in my terminal emulator-Terminator, with the following errors:

```
Error detected while processing /home/yp/dotfiles/.config/nvim/init.vim:
line   13:
E484: Can't open file /nvim/plugin-conf.vim
line   14:
line  360:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'gruvbox'
```

It seems to me that the environment variables are not loaded as they would be if I tried to access neovim directly from the terminal, but I can't find how to make it load the file with all my normal configuration.

My desktop entry:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=Neovim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
TryExec=nvim
Exec=terminator -e 'nvim %F'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=Text;editor;
Icon=nvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```

I would appreciate your help

Answer (score 1):

Actually found a workaround right before submitting:
I added source command to source my .zshrc .

`Exec=terminator -e 'source ~/.zshrc && nvim %F`

It's not the cleanest way and if there is a better way I'd love to hear it, but it works.

in context:

```
[Desktop Entry] 
Name=Neovim
GenericName=Text Editor
Comment=Edit text files
TryExec=nvim
Exec=terminator -e 'source ~/.zshrc && nvim %F'
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Keywords=Text;editor;
Icon=nvim
Categories=Utility;TextEditor;
StartupNotify=false
MimeType=text/english;text/plain;text/x-makefile;text/x-c++hdr;text/x-c++src;text/x-chdr;text/x-csrc;text/x-java;text/x-moc;text/x-pascal;text/x-tcl;text/x-tex;application/x-shellscript;text/x-c;text/x-c++;
```